# Add new line after finding last string in a region

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this input test.txt file with the output interleaved as #Expected in it (after finding the last line containing 1 1 1 1 within a *Title region

and this code in Python 3.6

```
index = 0
insert = False
currentTitle = ""
testfile = open("test.txt","r")    
content = testfile.readlines()
finalContent = content
testfile.close()
# Should change the below line of code I guess to adapt
#titles = ["TitleX","TitleY","TitleZ"]   
 
for line in content:
    index = index + 1
    for title in titles:
        if line in title+"\n":    
            currentTitle = line
            print (line)
    if line == "1 1 1 1\n":
        insert = True
    if (insert == True) and (line != "1 1 1 1\n"):
        finalContent.insert(index-1, currentTitle[:6] + "2" + currentTitle[6:])
        insert = False
 
f = open("test.txt", "w")
finalContent = "".join(finalContent)
f.write(finalContent)
f.close()
```

Update:

Actual output with the answer provided

```
*Title Test
12125
124125
asdas 1 1 1 1 
rthtr 1 1 1 1 
asdasf 1 1 1 1 
asfasf 1 1 1 1 
blabla 1 1 1 1 
#Expected "*Title Test2" here <-- it didn't add it
124124124
*Title Dunno
12125
124125
12763125 1 1 1 1 
whatever 1 1 1 1
*Title Dunno2
#Expected "*Title Dunno2" here <-- This worked great
214142122

#and so on for thousands of them..
```

Also is there a way to overwrite this in the test.txt file?

Comment: So you want to be able to find the last line with 1111 and add a title after it to mark the next region?

Comment: @JordanSimba Yes, that is correct. The last line with 1 1 1 1 within a region, then add the *Title[Name as previous one]2

Comment: `more_itertools.peekable(iterable)` this class let's you 'peek' ahead in an iterator without consuming it. This could help you check it the next line after a 1111 lines contains 1111 if not, insert title

Comment: @JordanSimba Thank you! Now I got a bit confused, as I never used more_itertools.peekable(iterable) before

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple regions with `1 1 1 1` after the same `Title`?

Comment: @tripleee re:last comment regarding multiple regions with 1 1 1 1 after the same Title, it should target the last one and add a new line with Previous Title name and adding 2 after it, exactly as in the above output (please see the expected results interleaved with #)

Comment: So if you have '#Title Poo`, `one`, `two 1 1 1 1`, `three`, `four 1 1 1 1`. `five`, we should add `#Title Poo2` both before `three` and `five`?

Comment: Boolean flags would work also. You've commented out the titles list, is that intentional right now? Also, does the code not work right now? Do you have an actual output

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the question. Title  Poo2 should be added just after five (as being the last line containing the 1 1 1 1 string within that Title Poo region.

Comment: @Nytro, does title always start with `*` if not how to identify title ?

Comment: @JordanSimba Hi, yes I commented the titles list on purpose. The code does not work right now, as I'm thinking of how to adjust it, hence no actual output, just an expected one as above.

Comment: @Sushanth Hello. Yes, the Title always starts in this format *Title [Name]

Comment: I tried to update your question based on comments but they have changed repeatedly. I already composed an answer based on a comment which is now deleted. Please be careful about stating your requirements up front. If there can't be multiple regions after a Title that's fine, too; we just need to have clear requirements.

Comment: @tripleee apologies for that,  I fully respect that. Please see the latest version updated

Comment: Your demo data has a space after `1 1 1 1` most of the time; is this a variation we need to take into account?

Comment: @tripleee if it is doable, yes, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are already reading the entire file into memory anyway, it's easy to scan through the lines twice; once to find the last transition out of a region after each title, and once to write the modified data back to the same filename, overwriting the previous contents.

I'm introducing a dictionary variable `transitions` where the keys are the indices of the lines which have a transition, and the value for each is the text to add at that point.

```py
transitions = dict()
in_region = False
reg_end = -1
current_title = None

with open("test.txt","r") as testfile:
    content = testfile.readlines()

for idx, line in enumerate(content):
    if line.startswith('*Title '):
        # Commit last transition before this to dict, if any
        if current_title:
            transitions[reg_end] = current_title
        # add suffix for printing
        current_title = line.rstrip('\n') + '2\n'
    elif line.strip().endswith(' 1 1 1 1'):
        in_region = True
        # This will be overwritten while we remain in the region
        reg_end = idx
    elif in_region:
        in_region = False

 if current_title:
    transitions[reg_end] = current_title

with open("test.txt", "w") as output:
    for idx, line in enumerate(content):
        output.write(line)
        if idx in transitions:
            output.write(transitions[idx])
```

This kind of "remember the last time we saw something" loop is very common, but takes some time getting used to. Inside the loop, keep in mind that we are looping over all the lines, and remembering some things we saw during a previous iteration of this loop. (Forgetting the last thing you were supposed to remember when you are finally out of the loop is also a very common bug!)

The `strip()` before we look for `1 1 1 1` normalizes the input by removing any surrounding whitespace. You could do other kinds of normalizations, too; normalizing your data is another very common technique for simplifying your logic.

Demo: https://ideone.com/GzNUA5

Comment: What they did was brilliant, amazing, I really do appreciate their work. Is there a way (based on the previous answer  without overwriting providing by they) to post a new line within each region just if the number of consecutive lines containing 1 1 1 1 is at least 5 within each region? Probably doable with a variable that counts the number of lines containing 1 1 1 1 within each region?

Comment: Sounds like you should post a new question with enough details and your best attempt.

Comment: If they want to have a look, it's cross-posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314680/how-to-post-a-new-line-at-the-end-of-each-title-region-with-titlename2-if-ther

Answer (score 1):

try this, using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

```
from itertools import zip_longest

with open("test.txt","r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

results, title = [], ""
for i, j in zip_longest(content, content[1:]):
    # extract title.
    if i.startswith("*"):
        title = i

    results.append(i)

    # compare value in i'th index with i+1'th (if mismatch add title)
    if "1 1 1 1" in i and "1 1 1 1" not in j:
        results.append(f'{title.strip()}2\n')

print("".join(results))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Is there a way to overwrite the test.txt file? such as imposing 'w' rather than print? Also can the new Title[Name]2 be on the same line? I noticed that for the moment it adds the Title[Name] but the 2 is on a new line below it.

Comment: @Nytro, seems to add in same line ``*Title Test2...*Title Dunno2`` can u check again.

Comment: yes sure, please see here: https://imgur.com/a/u8SUdax